# MongoDB and NUMA

Tags: mongodb, numa, numactl

MongoDB write performance is really slow on this machine with NUMA. I went through this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/ . I disabled zone reclaim and started mongodb with `numactl --interleave=all` command as mentioned.NUMA warning disappears now, but I couldn't get the performace. when I fired `numactl -s`, it shows

```
policy: default
preferred node: current
physcpubind: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
cpubind: 0 1
nodebind: 0 1
membind: 0 1
```

why can't i see policy = interleave. Am I missing something?. Can anyone please help me how to improve my write performace and/or disable this NUMA?.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to MongoDB and was going through some white papers.
https://webassets.mongodb.com/_com_assets/collateral/MongoDB-Performance-Best-Practices.pdf?_ga=1.50371949.595438063.1479457116 
This one says if you're running your MongoDB and clients on NUMA hardware, you should configure a memory interleave policy.